# Angular - Assign new value to FirebaseListObservable

Tags: javascript, angular, angularfire2

Not sure how this is suppose to be done.

`filter` is a Firebase list observable.

```
filter: FirebaseListObservable<UserModel[]>;
```

This is the query. It gets all users with a specific occupation.

```
this.filter = this.db.list('occupationsUsers/' + occupation + '/users');
```

Then I use an `<md-list>` which works. It displays all users with occupation.

```
<md-list>

            <md-list-item *ngFor="let user of filter | async" [value]="user.email">{{user.email}}
              <button md-button [mdMenuTriggerFor]="menu">Menu</button>
              <md-menu #menu="mdMenu">
                <button md-menu-item (click)="removeUserFromFilterList(user.email)">Delete</button>
              </md-menu>
            </md-list-item>
          </md-list>
```

removeUserFromFilterList

```
  removeUserFromFilterList(userEmail: string) {
    var index = this.eventForm['guests'].indexOf(userEmail);
    this.filter = this.eventForm['guests'].splice(index, 1);
  }
```

The error:

```
ERROR Error: InvalidPipeArgument: '[object Object]' for pipe 'AsyncPipe'
    at invalidPipeArgumentError
```

How do I populate `this.filter` with the new updated user list and keep it working with the firebase query?

Comment: Your `this.db.list` operation returns an object. You need an array to iterate over `*ngFor`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`this.filter` as you mention , is a `FirebaseListObservable`. and as i understand , `this.eventForm` is just an array(and not like `this.filter`).
i would recommend you to use one of the following methods:
`this.filter.update('key-of-some-data', { object to remove });`
or
`this.filter.remove('key-of-some-data');`
you can read more about that on
[click here](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/3-retrieving-data-as-lists.md)

Comment: I ll check it. Thank you!